# How to make jQuery JSON request and use response data to change html element values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm not good at JQuery at all, in fact this is my first encounter due to Shopify. In other words I'm completely lost.

This is what I was able to do so far.

```
function FindPlayer()
{

    var playerid = $('input[id=playerId]').val();
    var clubname = $('input[id=teamname]').val();


    $("#searchBar").attr('data-user-input', value);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://website.com/index.php?player=" + playerid + "&club=" + clubname,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
```

}

The json response is going to look like this:

```
  [{"playerFound":"true","tradeid":"123456"}]
```

I want to then check if playerFound is true or false before setting this element:

```
  <input id="tradeId" type="hidden" name="attributes[tradeid]" />
```

This is probably pretty basic for JQuery users but not for me any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://website.com/index.php?player=" + playerid + "&club=" + clubname,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if(data[0].playerFound == "true")
        {
           $('#tradeId').val(data[0].tradeid);
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: JQuery is such a confusing language but from what I can see it's very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since content type is JSON you can simply use like this

```
   success: function (data) {               
            if(data.playerFound == "true"){
                $('#tradeId').attr('name',data.tradeid) // if you want to change name
                $('#tradeId').val(data.tradeid)// if you want to change value
            }          
   }
```